# Как к одному telegram токену подключить несколько устройств?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как к одному telegram токену подключить несколько устройств (желательно без сервера).
Есть программа в которой запускается telegram бот. Эту программу могут запускать одновременно несколько устройств, но Telegram выдаёт ошибку при подключении более одного клиента.

[image: Ошибка:]

Мне просто нужно что бы к одному telegram боту могли подключаться несколько устройств

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не думаю, что это возможно, иначе как телеграмм поймет какой обработчик выполнять. И что это за специфичная задача, в которой вам понадобилось запускать несколько одинаковых обработчик с разных устройств.